# How to style an <HR> html element?

Tags: html, css

I need to style an `<HR>` similar to what is shown in the picture: it is like two lines one over the other. I've seen this somewher, then I guess it can be done, but I don't remember where.

[image]

I got this css code so far, but I only get the blue line:

```
hr {
margin: 0px auto 10px;
background: #009edf;
width: 200px;
text-align: center; }
```

Comment: There you go: http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/ufdHL/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:before` :pseudo-element.

```css
hr {
  position: relative;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #B2B2B2;
}
hr:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 6px solid #0093E6;
  color: blue;
  left: 20%;
  top: -4px;
}
```

```html
<hr />
```

Comment: Ok, it looks fine in Firefox and Chrome, but the grey line looks like double in Safari. Not a problem at all, but is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @JPashs - Nope! Don't have any solution for that. Maybe, If you could show me an image.(Linux user)

Comment: Now it looks fine. cache issue I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this:

```css
hr {
    height:2px;
    border:0;
    background-color: #444;
    line-height:20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

hr:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #111;
}

hr:after {
    content: 'O';
    color:#ccc;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#222;
    width:60px;
    margin-top:-10px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%);  
}
```

```html
<hr>
```

Comment: Good use of pseudo-elements method.

Comment: I see it is the way but I don't know how to show a line instead of the "O": http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/ufdHL/

Comment: @JPashs give it a height and then you can remove the O

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick,

```
hr{
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    height: 2px;
    background: transparent;
}
```